# Show AutoCompleteTextView Popup always above of TextField

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to develop small app in which i used AutoCompleteTextView and i used

```
           simpleCursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                      // my stub here
          }
```

As my filtration goes specific ,my Dropdown(Anchor) goes beneath of Virtual keyboard. That means supppose that  first i search with 
**DR.** then it shows list of 15 doctor in Dropdown(Anchor) with no any problem. But as i typed **DR.Kum** , now Dropdown(Anchor) have only one name so that Dropdown(Anchor) goes down of virtual keyboard . When it has 15 name of list it showing perfectly.How to show Dropdown(Anchor) always above of AutoCompleteTextView.??

Comment: I am also struggling with same problem...Any one have any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by one trick

```
       // It will capture number item in your DropDown . If number of item in drop is 2
      // or 1 , then hide keyboard.
      if(cur_hide_keyboard.getCount() ==2 || cur_hide_keyboard.getCount() ==1){
                                hideKeyBoard();
                            }

         private void hideKeyBoard() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(doctorsName.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a subclass of your anchor. In most cases, the anchor is `AutoCompleteTextView`.
2. Override the `getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame` method in this way, for example:

   ```
   class AutoCompleteTextViewImpl extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {
       private boolean mShowDropDownAlwaysAbove;

       public AutoCompleteTextViewImpl(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public void setShowDropDownAlwaysAbove(boolean showAbove) {
           mShowDropDownAlwaysAbove = showAbove;
       }

       @Override
       public void getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(Rect outRect) {
           super.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(outRect);
           if (mShowDropDownAlwaysAbove)
                outRect.bottom = -3000; // hack for https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/android/widget/PopupWindow.java#L1449
       }
   }
   ```

Now `dropDown` will always show above.
The reason is hidden [in this portion of the code](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/android/widget/PopupWindow.java#L1449) responsible for calculating the top coordinate.